# how to show hidden div on scroll down when scroll bar does not exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I show a hidden div on Scroll down when the height on the visible div is fixed and scroll bar does not exist

I tried:

```
   $(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(this).scrollTop()>0)
     {

        $('.b').show();
     }

 });
```

but i think the scroll event is dependent on the existence of a scroll bar.

https://jsfiddle.net/MFUw3/1965/

Comment: If you page is not long enough (height wise) then maybe the scroll event isn't appropriate. But if it will be in the future and you want to test. Why not set a height on the body that is larger than your screen.

Comment: @floor Thanks for the reply. I want the visible div to be the height of the viewport - until scrolled up.

Comment: Yeah so maybe scroll isn't what you want to use. I think there is a event for mouse wheel. So you can trigger something like hide and show on user mouse wheel up or down.